# Printer Driver Update

Tags: windows, printing, driver

I am updating the printer drivers in my print server, but the first driver I done was in Chinese.
After about 20 minutes we managed to get the English version installed.

That worked for most of my users, but a few of them had the Chinese driver pushed into their PCs.

Now they are fixed in Chinese, since the driver doesn't recognize any changes in version.

Any way I can force a local uninstall of these drivers and force a new installation to pull the English version in place?

I tried Deleting the printers and re-adding them,
Tried deleting the enviroment from registry and put a english backup from a working PC in place,
Tried uninstalling the drivers from the printer menagement, but says the printer is in use...

Nothing is making it prompt the English setup.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Windows can delete the drivers if you do it while the spooling service is working it out.
Have both of them ready and once the service is stopping you delete the package of drivers.
That removes them from the PC.